# Table of Contents numbered in Roman in Lyx

Tags: lyx, roman-numerals

I use Lyx 2.1, document class : report.
I want the pages table of contents, list of figures and list of tables etc. be numbered with roman numerals.
I put this tag before the table of Contents :

```
\pagenumbering{Roman}
```

and this tag before the general introduction :

```
\cleardoublepage\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

The problem for Roman numerals, only the 1st page Table of Contents is numbered. I want the other pages will be numbered as (the 2nd page table of contents and list of figures etc).

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass{report} 

\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}
\begin{onehalfspace}
\pagenumbering{roman}\tableofcontents{}

\listoffigures

\end{onehalfspace}

\listoftables


\pagenumbering{arabic}


\chapter*{\noun{Inroduction générale}\setcounter{page}{1}}

\end{document} % was missing
```

Comment: `R`oman or `r`oman numerals?

Comment: roman (i, ii, etc.)

Comment: Writing  `\frontmatter` before the table of contents and `\mainmatter` before the main text should do the trick (not sure for the report class. If it doesn't work (it does with the book class), you can locally change the page style.

Comment: @Bernard `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` isn't defined in `report`.

Comment: @Torbjørn T: I didn't remember (never used this class).  It should be enough to play with`\pagenumbering{roman}` and `\pagenumbering{arabic}`, resetting the page counter in between (and maybe a `\clear(double)page`).

Comment: LyX has nothing to do with this

Comment: @leo Only in terms of how you actually apply the solution.

Comment: Why not just switch to `book` class?

Comment: I need to document class report for several reasons

Comment: I suppose at least part of the point of Christian's answer was to demonstrate that the default setup has got page numbers on all pages of the ToC. Hence, you must have done something to turn off the page numbering, i.e. changing the page style somewhere. But without an example it is hard be more precise.

Comment: To create an example, first create the smallest LyX-document you can that demonstrates the problem. Then either 1) open that .lyx file in a text editor, copy the entire file, and paste it into your question, or 2) export to a LaTeX file (File->Export->LaTeX(pdflatex)), open this file and copy-paste all the text into your post. See also http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: I added the code to my publication

Comment: @GoldRay: I suppose, it is the line `\pagenumbering{roman}\tableofcontents{}\thispagestyle{empty}` in your document which is responsible for the 'faulty' behaviour

Comment: Specifically, it's `\thispagestyle{empty}` I guess. Remove that and you should be fine. (@ChristianHupfer You could modify your answer when you have time.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. its works but for the list of tables numbering in arabic and not roman. I edited my code

Comment: \begin{document}
    \begin{onehalfspace}
    \pagenumbering{roman}\tableofcontents{}
    
    \listoffigures
    
    \end{onehalfspace}
    
    \listoftables
    
    
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    
    
    \chapter*{\noun{Inroduction générale}\setcounter{page}{1}}

Comment: Please edit your question to include new code like that, don't add it in comments. (And I really would appreciate *complete* examples, starting with `\documentclass`, ending with `\end{document}`. But remove most of the text of course, only the `\chapter`/`\section` headings is important here, I guess.)

Comment: Move the `\listoftables` to immediately after `\listoffigures` (inside `onehalfspacing`).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I have updated the answer

Comment: Thank you, finally its works. I need your opinion: should I put the tables of contents, list of figures and list of the pictures at the table of contents, or not ?

Comment: @GoldRay: As far as I know, there is no general rule, but most authors use this order: `\tableofcontents\listoffigures\listoftables` (the order of figures and tables can be switched, however)

Comment: Should I put them in the table of contents?
like this:
Table of Contents i
List of Figures iii
List of Tables v

Comment: @GoldRay: You could them into the toc, as I have shown in the updated code, it is safer, however, to call a `\cleardoublepage`.

Comment: TorbjørnT & Christian Hupfer : Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the standard setup is applied, **no** empty second page of the ToC should appear, regardless whether `\tableofcontents`, `\listoffigures` etc. is used.

I have used a loop to generate dummy chapters, dummy figures and dummy tables just in order to fill up the corresponding `list of something` (;-)) and removed the `\thispagestyle{empty}` used directly after `\tableofcontents` by the OP.

Basically, Torbjorn T. changed already the code sample in the OP to a working one ;-)

**Edited version, with `list of figures` and `list of tables` also in the toc

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{setspace}%

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}%
\usepackage{forloop}  % Only for quick chapters ;-)

%\usepackage{hyperref}%

\newcounter{loopcounter}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}%
\begin{onehalfspace}%
%\phantomsection% if hyperref is used, then \phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\contentsname}%
\tableofcontents%
\cleardoublepage
%\phantomsection% if hyperref is used, then \phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}%
\listoffigures%
\cleardoublepage
%\phantomsection% if hyperref is used, then \phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}%
\listoftables%

\end{onehalfspace}%
\clearpage

% Just a proof that `\pagenumbering{arabic}` resets the page counter
\setcounter{page}{100}

\pagenumbering{arabic}



\forloop{loopcounter}{1}{\number\value{loopcounter} < 21}{%

\chapter{Chapter \number\value{loopcounter}}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline
1  & 2 & 3 \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Dummy table}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}%
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4cm]{somefig}%
\caption{Dummy figure}
\end{figure}%

}



\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

**Editorial note** I kept the screenshot, since nothing visually changed for that part of the document.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but your solution did nothing.

Comment: @GoldRay: Well, that's sad but perhaps you should post a small document exactly reproducing your problem. Otherwise users here can only guess what goes wrong... Just a small MWE ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Define your own `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` in the preamble. For LyX `Document->Preferences->Preamble`:

```
\documentclass{report} 
\newcommand\frontmatter{\cleardoublepage\pagenumbering{roman}}
\newcommand\mainmatter{\cleardoublepage\pagenumbering{arabic}}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoftables

\mainmatter
\singlespacing

\chapter*{Inroduction générale}
\Blinddocument
\begin{figure}
foo\caption{bar}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
foo\caption{bar}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]